# config bin_path with Umbrella: 502 bad gateway

Tags: kubernetes, umbrella

Recently I had to work on setting up a gateway using Umbrella. I am relatively new to this one. This was what I got after trying everything from my old developer (he left the team already, and I could not keep in touch with him):

```
2023-05-22T15:00:33.27703 starting trafficserver...
2023-05-22T15:00:33.28531 [E. Mgmt] log ==> [TrafficManager] using root directory '/opt/api-umbrella'
2023-05-22T15:00:33.28809 Fatal: [LocalManager::LocalManager] please set bin path 'proxy.config.bin_path'
```

Any idea to solve it?